# How to upgrade Pulseaudio to the latest available version?

Tags: pulseaudio

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 (I can't upgrade right now) and I'm using pulseaudio 2.x.

I have some sound issues with VLC and others and I'd like to know if I can upgrade to pulseaudio 3.x or even 4.x with this Ubuntu version, and if i can is there an up-to-date repository?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Warning:**
>   Upgrading pulseaudio should be the last resort when trying to fix an audio issues. Usually it is a missing setting, bad configuration, or incompatible hardware which cause such issues. Only if we **know for sure** that our issue was related to a bug that is now fixed, or in case we need new features added in a newer version we may try to upgrade pulseaudio.

Please also read about usage and limitations of a ppa:

- [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)

---

For Ubuntu 12.04 there is a [ppa from the Ubuntu Audio Development Team](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-audio-dev/+archive/ppa) which includes pulseaudio 3.0.:

```
ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa
```

For latest and development versions of Ubuntu another ppa offers the latest supposedly stable pulseaudio version **for testing**:

```
ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev/pulse-testing
```

Installing pulseaudio from both ppa may introduce new bugs, and it may become difficult to downgrade later, so you should not be surprised if your sound issue became worse rather than better.

Comment: Hello ! First, thanks for your answer.
I have issues when pausing/resuming VLC (mostly with big video files but happens with "regular" files too) resulting in desynced audio/video.
VLC itself asks me to upgrade and i have to admit this "bug" is becoming a pain in the ass for video editing (i don't really care about having latest pulseaudio version tbh)
So ! I'm gonna try upgrading to 3.0 to see if it fix the issue !

Thanks again :)